# SSAS MDX Create set fails with on an empty set

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2012, ssas, mdx

I am currently maintaining some legacy MDX code. After some ETL changes in one of the columns I have now only False values - previously there were both True and False values to be found in the [Bool1]. My question is hot to change the below code fragment so that it will not fail with only False values?

```
CREATE SET CURRENTCUBE.[Set1]
    AS { [Customer].[Bool1].&amp;[True] }, DISPLAY_FOLDER = 'Dimension Filters';
```

The error I am getting is:

The level '&[True]' object was not found in the cube when the string, [Customer].[Bool1].&[True], was parsed.

Maybe there is a reference later to this object and as it is empty it fails?

Answer (score 0):

I worked it around with set subtraction so that I do not call the &[True] level which does not exists:

{ [Customer].[Bool1].MEMBERS - [Customer].[Bool1].&[False] }